# How to serve static files in nginx conditionally based on proxy response?

Tags: api, nginx, static-files, serving, limited-user

I have a folder `/static/uploads/limited` and I need to config nginx to serve some files to specific users.  I also have an API `/api/auth/canIDownloadThis` which responses a json like

```
{
  "result:"true"
}
```

How can I make nginx to check the response of my API proxy_pass before serving that specific folder?

the pseudo code I need is something like this:

```
location /static/uploads/limited{
    IF /api/canIdownloadThis IS TRUE
    THEN alias /my_secret_folder_path
}
```

Since I don't want to use basic_auth.  Thank you.

Comment: Haven't used it, but something that goes into this direction is [ngx_http_auth_request_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html). If your auth API returns correct HTTP status codes, this might work.

Comment: Thank you.  You can write down this and I will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @stephenKing, I need to compile nginx with `--with-http_auth_request_module` and then create an API that responses `403` or `200`

```
location ~* /(\w+)/static/limited/(?:/_[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)?/(.*)$ 
{
    auth_request /IC/contents/can_i_access_limited;
    alias /home/A/iB-system/C/$1/static/uploads/$2;
   }
```